# Injecting backup Data into new Database

Tags: sql

At the moment I have 2 SQL data backups. The clients would like any of the "lost" data be inputted back into the current live version.

The table name is called Interactions.

Each interaction can have a list of InteractionAttendees.

There is a link - `InteractionAttendees.Interaction_Id = Interaction.Id`

I was able to query the backups and I've identified what needs to be injected into the new one but I'm not sure where do I go from here. It looks like there are some interactions from backup 1 and backup 2 that have the same primary keys. How do I inject the old data into the new database?

**Example**

Sql DB1

Interactions

```
Id
1
```

Interaction Attendee

```
Id    InteractionId    PersonId
1          1               5
```

Sql DB2

Interactions

```
Id
1
```

Interaction Attendee

```
Id    InteractionId    PersonId
1          1               10
```

Current Live Database

Interactions

```
Id
1
2
```

Interaction Attendee

```
Id    InteractionId    PersonId
1          1               7
2          2               55
3          2               77
```

After injection of the two SQL queries, it should be the following:

Interactions

```
Id
1
2
3
4
```

Interaction Attendee

```
Id    InteractionId    PersonId
1          1               7
2          2               55
3          2               77
4          3               5
5          4               10
```